# Pointers clarification in makecontext function

Tags: c, linux, unix

I have been implementing a user threads library as part of my assignment.
I didn't understand the `makecontext` function:

```
makecontext(&(mainthread->threadctx),(void(*)(void))start_funct,1,args)
```

What does `(void(*)(void))start_funct` exactly mean? And why do I have to write it this way?
Can't I just write it as

```
makecontext(&(mainthread->threadctx),start_funct,1,args) ?
```

Please be patient with me, I am not yet comfortable with pointers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void(*)(void)` means "pointer to a function that takes no parameters and returns `void`".

Therefore `(void(*)(void))start_funct` is casting `start_funct` (which we can assume is some kind of function pointer)` to the above type. (There is a [very useful online tool](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=%28void%28%2a%29%28void%29%29start_funct) that can help you with this until you get more comfortable reading declarations).

You have to write it this way because the signature of `start_funct` is not `void start_funct(void)`, so casting is required.

Comment: Note: `makecontext` actually expects a `void(*)()`, that is, a pointer to a function accepting an unspecified number of arguments and returning `void`

Comment: @Jon Thanks! Thanks for the online tool, will be handy.